# Leer un archivo csv como una matriz en java

Tags: java, csv

He estado experimentando con las bibliotecas com.opencsv y javacsv pero siempre me encuentro con algún escollo con estos paquetes: no puedo escribir la primera fila, no puedo leer columnas, entre otros problemas. Mi pregunta es: ¿Existe algún paquete que me permita leer y escribir un csv referenciando fila y columna como si fuera una planilla de cálculo o una matriz? He visto algo del paquete super CSV pero tampoco encontré la solución en este paquete.

Answer (score 1):

Es posible que no necesites una libreria.

Puedes cargar el contenido de un archivo de texto usando

```
Files.lines(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
```

Luego puedes separar por el caracter de separacion y guardar en una lista que luego puedes iterar:

```
String path = "C:\\data\\data.csv";
ArrayList<String[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
Files.lines(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8).forEach(x->list.add(x.split(';')));

//Consigue el elemento en la columna 3 de la linea 23
String elementoBuscado = list.get(22)[2];
```

Arraylist puede no ser la coleccion mas eficiente para esto dependiendo en el tamaño de los datos y de la ram disponible, pero como ejemplo tiene que servir.

Nota: La carga en arraylist con lambda requiere al menos Java 8, de otra manera tendrás que iterar.